# Facebook API without access_token

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

How to receive to posts of the user of Facebook without access_token just by i.e GET or POST requests?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can't get the user's posts without authorizing your app. Also you cannot use Facebook Api without Access Tokens.